# How to make a linearlayout filling remaining space in a relativelayout?

Tags: android, layout

I've got a relativelayout with three linearlayouts as children. The last one has a fixed height and has android:layout_alignParentBottom set to "true". While the middle one is properly positioned below the first one, it goes as far as the bottom of the screen, so that its lower part is overlapped by the third one.

What's wrong?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/red_arrow_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/no_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    //stuff

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nooo... the solution is much simpler! You forgot to say that you wanted the second linear layout to be above the third one :) Yes, the second linear layout must have BOTH         `android:layout_below="@+id/category"` and `android:layout_above="@+id/nav_bar"`. I tested it and it works.

But of course, you can use weights to achieve the same results, it is just going to be harder...

Here is your XML with the change I mentioned (tested it in eclipse):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/red_arrow_left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/no_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
//stuff

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 32):

You could try using layout weights to control the relative sizes of the child layouts. There is an [article on my blog](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/111) which gives some information on the use of layout weights.

As an example, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="29dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cat_name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/category"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/android:empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="no_item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    //stuff

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout` has been replaced by a `LinearLayout`, all of the relative positioning tags have been removed, and a `layout_weight` attribute has been added to the centre `LinearLayout` which will cause it to stretch to fill the available space.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an id to your second LinearLayout

```
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/category" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_ID">
```

and in the third layout add `android:layout_below="@id/YOUR_ID"`

```
   <LinearLayout 
       android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
       android:layout_below="@id/YOUR_ID"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
       android:layout_height="40dp" 
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Comment: Just to add to this, why is the 3rd LinearLayout also declaring the xmlns:android tag? I thought you only did that in the root object?

Comment: Did not see that:) Just made a copy/paste, but you are right. What is it doing there?