# android Imageview top and bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get a layout that will have a `ImageView` anchored to the *top*, an `ImageView` anchored to the *bottom* and a `LinearLayout` that fills the *middle*

the `LinearLayout` (or I may want to use a `ScrollView`) needs to expand to fill the space depending on the resolution, screen size etc...

I tried combinations of `fill_parent`, `wrap_content` etc.. but can't get it anchored to the *bottom*

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background2"
android:background="#EEEDEB"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="174px"
        android:src="@drawable/sodexotop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt1"
    android:onClick="clk_raynes"
    android:text="sitebutton"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50px" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rutlishbtn"
        android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/butt1"
        android:onClick="clk_rutlish"
        android:text="Site2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50px" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/harrisbtn"
        android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:background="@drawable/butt1"
        android:onClick="clk_harris"
        android:text="Site3"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_ricards"
                android:text="Site4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_btn10"
                android:text="Site5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="420px"
    android:layout_height="99px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_btn11"
                android:text="Site6"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

           <Button
            android:id="@+id/picbtn3"

            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="190px"

            android:text="³"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="qrbtn" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="174px"
        android:src="@drawable/sodexobottom" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your layout code

Comment: please add your code so we can help you

Comment: Probably this will help [Fill space in LinearLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880513/how-to-make-a-linearlayout-filling-remaining-space-in-a-relativelayout)

Comment: have you considered using relative layout. Its perfect for this kind of job

Comment: Just a side note: DONT use px as unit. NEVER! Use dp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background2"
    android:background="#EEEDEB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="174px"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sodexotop" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_raynes"
                android:text="sitebutton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rutlishbtn"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_rutlish"
                android:text="Site2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/harrisbtn"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_harris"
                android:text="Site3"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_ricards"
                android:text="Site4"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_btn10"
                android:text="Site5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="420px"
                android:layout_height="99px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="clk_btn11"
                android:text="Site6"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="50px" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/picbtn3"

                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="190px"

                android:text="³"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/butt1"
                android:onClick="qrbtn" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="174px"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sodexobottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your layout file like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
            android:padding="16dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/topImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>            
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/yourContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topImage"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomImage"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There is no need of a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout ... With RelativeLayout you already can layout the children on the desired position. So the Buttons can be positioned directly in RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Have three linear layouts initially with weight parameters set. Use ImageView in the first and last layouts. Use the middle layout as per you requirement.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:weightSum="6">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight = "4" >

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/background2"
      android:background="#EEEDEB"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="174dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sodexotop" />

     <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:background="#ffffff"
       android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

 <Button
android:id="@+id/button4"
android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/butt1"
android:onClick="clk_raynes"
android:text="sitebutton"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textSize="50sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/rutlishbtn"
    android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt1"
    android:onClick="clk_rutlish"
    android:text="Site2"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/harrisbtn"
    android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:background="@drawable/butt1"
    android:onClick="clk_harris"
    android:text="Site3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_ricards"
            android:text="Site4"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_btn10"
            android:text="Site5"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="420dp"
android:layout_height="99dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt1"
            android:onClick="clk_btn11"
            android:text="Site6"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/picbtn3"

        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="190dp"

        android:text="³"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/butt1"
        android:onClick="qrbtn" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="174dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sodexobottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I've added a `ScrollView`, if you don't need the `ScrollView`, then just set `android:layout_height="0dp"` & `android:layout_weight="1"` to your middle `LinearLayout`.